# Using magento how to display attribute dropdown filters on toolbar in list.phtml page?

Tags: magento, filter

I have to display product attribute filters(dropdowns) on list page toolbar. any body tell me how to put filters on list page?

The code I am trying to use is:

```
$_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();
 $_helper = $this->helper('catalog/output');
```

I put a filter in the toolbar section using the below code. I am not getting any result. `metal_type` is an attribute which has options "Gold" and "Silver" .

```
<select id='filter' onchange="ajaxfunction()">
<?php foreach($_productCollection as $product): ?>
 <option value="<?php $product->getmetal_type() ?>"><?php $product->getmetal_type() ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do manually, by load one collection on starts of the page.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
```

And you put you combo box like this:

```
<select id='filter' onchange="ajaxfunction()">
    <?php foreach($collection as $product): ?>
     <option value="<?= $product->getAttributeYouWantUseToFilter()" ?>"><?= $product->getAttributeYouWantUseToFilter()" ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

On ajax you call your action to filter.